# Time based solution of an LC circuit at resonance

Tags: capacitor, inductor, frequency, resonance

I am trying to solve for the voltage across the capacitor in an LC circuit driven by a sinusoidal voltage at the resonant frequency, \$\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}\$. My solution contains a scaling factor of the resonant frequency, \$\omega_n\$.

Does a higher resonant frequency actually make the voltage grow faster, or have I made a mistake somewhere in my calculations? Below is a screenshot of my notes.

[image: Circuit]
[image: Calculations]

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the images to be as big as possible (the monitor I'm on is pretty low res so I cant get much better than it is now).

Comment: It does grow linearly to infinity and it grows at a faster rate if the resonant frequency is higher.

Comment: huh, fair enough. Seems odd that it grows faster with a higher frequency imo but I guess I will just have to think it through more.

Comment: It grows faster with higher frequency because it's all about energy per cycle and, a higher frequency therefore has more cycles per second and thus more stored energy for a given time. Try simulating it to see.

Comment: Yeah, I will have a go with a simulation, but I have sorta figured it out. My original thinking was that the shorter wavetime would counteract that, but I guess dv/dt will also be larger so a larger current will flow, so after rethinking it, it does make sense that it increases faster with a faster wavelength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plot of two tuned circuits with one running at 159.155 Hz and one running at 15.9155 Hz: -

[image]

Made by: -

[image]

The slower frequency rises at one tenth of the rate of the faster frequency. In detail: -

[image]

The peaks aren't quite aligned because I chose frequencies that are 10:1 but, Vc1 indicates a peak that is 488.517 volts whilst Vc2 (a tad earlier) is 48.695 volts (i.e. about 10:1 in ratio).

Comment: Thanks for the simulation graphs, makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You last formula \$v_c(t)= \dfrac{\omega_n t}{2}sin(\omega_nt)\$ means the envelope ramps at the rate of \$ \dfrac{\omega_n t}{2}\$ .

Thus for  \$\omega_0=1000\$ [rad/s] the peak voltage is 500*Vin in 1 second.

if \$L/C=1=Zo^2\$.  Would you expect the peak current to be 500A at 1sec. for 1Vpk input at resonance?